# Не срабатывает слот в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть функция, которая вызывает слот:

```
void notesWindow::notNotes(QGridLayout *notesLay)
{
    QLabel *notNotesLbl = new QLabel("Заметок еще нет. Добавьте свою первую заметку.");
    notNotesLbl->setAlignment(AlignCenter);

    QPushButton *addNoteBut = new QPushButton("Добавить заметку");

    notesLay->addWidget(notNotesLbl, 0, 0);
    notesLay->addWidget(addNoteBut, 1, 0);

    connect(addNoteBut, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addNotes()));
}
```

По сути должен сработать вот этот слот:

```
void notesWindow::addNotes()
{
    QMessageBox* pmbx = new QMessageBox("MessageBox",
                        "<b>A</b> <i>Simple</i>   <u>Message</u>",
                        QMessageBox::Information,
                        QMessageBox::Yes,
                        QMessageBox::No,
                        QMessageBox::Cancel | QMessageBox::Escape);
}
```

Но он не срабатывает .h файл:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Qt;

class notesWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    notesWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void showMainTopBar(QHBoxLayout *topBarLay);
    void notNotes(QGridLayout *notesLay);
    void readNotesFile(char *fileName);

private:
    int amountNotes = 0;
    char fileName[10] = "notes.txt";

public slots:
    void addNotes();
};
```

Comment: При исполнении программы есть какой-то вывод? Есть строки вроде "no such slot..."?

Comment: notNotes(...) то предварительно вызывался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Убедитесь, что функция, использующая Ваш слот, вызывается в программе хоть раз. По этой причине имеет смысл прописывать все соединения в конструкторе - так будет обеспечена гарантия того, что соединение было осуществлено. (Разумеется, для этого Вы должны создать объект этого класса в теле main() ).
2. В случае, если слот содержится в классе, из которого производится соединение, то можно воспользоваться сокращенной формой метода connect (), опустив третий параметр (pReceiver), указывающий на объект-получатель. Другими словами, если в качестве объекта-получателя должен стоять указатель this, его можно просто не указывать:

`MyClass::MyClass()
{
connect(pSender, SIGNAL(signalMethod()), SLOT(slot()));
}`

3. Также существует альтернативный вариант метода connect(), преимущество которого заключается в том, что все ошибки соединения сигналов со слотами выявляются на этапе компиляции программы, а не при ее исполнении, как это происходит в классическом варианте метода connect(). Прототип альтернативного метода выглядит так:
   `QObject::connect(const QObject* sender,
   const QMetaMethod& signal,
   const QObject* receiver,
   const QMetaMethod& slot,
   Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection
   );`
   Вот так выглядит аналогичное соединение при помощи альтернативного метода
   connect():

   `QObject::connect(pSender, &SenderClass::signalMethod,
   pReceiver, &ReceiverClass::slotMethod
   );`

---

Благодаря именно тому, что используются указатели на методы сигналов и слотов классов напрямую, если Вы вдруг ошибетесь с названием сигнала или слота, Ваша ошибка будет выявлена сразу в процессе компиляции программы.

Answer (score 0):

Попытаюсь побыть немного экстрасенсом. Смею предположить, что Ваше заявление что слот не срабатывает, подразумевает что `QMessageBox`, не отображается. Но тут скорее проблема не с сигналами-слотами, а с самим кодом.

```
void notesWindow::addNotes()
{
    QMessageBox* pmbx = new QMessageBox("MessageBox",
                    "<b>A</b> <i>Simple</i>   <u>Message</u>",
                    QMessageBox::Information,
                    QMessageBox::Yes,
                    QMessageBox::No,
                    QMessageBox::Cancel | QMessageBox::Escape);
}
```

Этот код не будет показывать `QMessageBox`, для того чтоб что-то было показано, необходимо добавить вызов `exec`, и не забыть удалить ненужный указатель.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox* pmbx = new QMessageBox("MessageBox",
                            "<b>A</b> <i>Simple</i>   <u>Message</u>",
                            QMessageBox::Information,
                            QMessageBox::Yes,
                            QMessageBox::No,
                            QMessageBox::Cancel | QMessageBox::Escape);
    pmbx->exec();
    pmbx->deleteLater();
}
```

А еще лучше вообще отказаться от динамического создания объекта, потому что функция `exec` блокирующая.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox pmbx("MessageBox",
                            "<b>A</b> <i>Simple</i>   <u>Message</u>",
                            QMessageBox::Information,
                            QMessageBox::Yes,
                            QMessageBox::No,
                            QMessageBox::Cancel | QMessageBox::Escape);
    pmbx.exec();
}
```